Migration from Node 14 to Node 18 - The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler'
Recently I updated Node 14 to Node 18.20.4. I changed templates and related components so when I executed ng serve there were no errors in terminal console. However, when I execute npm run start or npm run webpack:dev I got the runtime error in web browser terminal console:
"Uncaught Error: The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available. The injectable is part of a library that has been partially compiled.
However, the Angular Linker has not processed the library such that JIT compilation is used as fallback. Ideally, the library is processed using the Angular Linker to become fully AOT compiled. Alternatively, the JIT compiler should be loaded by bootstrapping using '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic' or '@angular/platform-server', or manually provide the compiler with 'import "@angular/compiler";' before bootstrapping."
Here is the list of some other weird errors I get in runtime along with the first one:
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/shared/login/login.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\shared\login\login.component.ts) 11:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\shared\login\login.component.ts(11,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type 'string[]'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\layouts\navbar\navbar.component.ts) 19:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\layouts\navbar\navbar.component.ts(19,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '() => { exact: boolean; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/configuration/configuration.service.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\configuration\configuration.service.ts) 16:43-48
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\configuration\configuration.service.ts(16,44)
      TS2339: Property 'beans' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/logs/logs.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\logs\logs.component.ts) 12:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\logs\logs.component.ts(12,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '(a0: any) => { total: any; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/logs/logs.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\logs\logs.component.ts) 128:89-103
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\logs\logs.component.ts(128,90)
      TS2339: Property 'effectiveLevel' does not exist on type 'unknown'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-delete-dialog.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-delete-dialog.component.ts) 12:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-delete-dialog.component.ts(12,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '(a0: any) => { login: any; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-update.component.ts) 14:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-update.component.ts(14,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '() => { max: number; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-update.component.ts) 15:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-update.component.ts(15,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c1' must be of type '(a0: any) => any[]', but here has type '() => { max: number; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/admin/user-management/user-management-update.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-update.component.ts) 16:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\admin\user-management\user-management-update.component.ts(16,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c2' must be of type '(a0: any) => any[]', but here has type '() => { min: number; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password/password.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\password\password.component.ts) 12:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\password\password.component.ts(12,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '(a0: any) => { username: any; }'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password-reset/init/password-reset-init.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\password-reset\init\password-reset-init.component.ts) 11:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\password-reset\init\password-reset-init.component.ts(11,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type 'string[]'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/account/password-reset/finish/password-reset-finish.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\password-reset\finish\password-reset-finish.component.ts) 13:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\password-reset\finish\password-reset-finish.component.ts(13,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type 'string[]'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/account/register/register.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\register\register.component.ts) 13:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\register\register.component.ts(13,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type 'string[]'.
ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/account/settings/settings.component.ts (C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\settings\settings.component.ts) 13:4-7
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\account\settings\settings.component.ts(13,5)
      TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.  Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '(a0: any) => { username: any; }'.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\entity.routes.ts 3:34-67
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\entity.routes.ts(3,35)
      TS2306: File 'C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\check-lista\check-lista.route.ts' is not a module.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\entity.routes.ts 4:40-87
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\entity.routes.ts(4,41)
      TS2306: File 'C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\check-lista-stavke\check-lista-stavke.route.ts' is not a module.
...
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\odeljenje\radniks-by-odeljenje.component.ts(10,31)
      TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/entities/radnik/radnik.service.ts' is not a module.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\odeljenje\radniks-by-odeljenje.component.ts 11:60-90
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\odeljenje\radniks-by-odeljenje.component.ts(11,61)
      TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/shared/sort/sort-state.ts' is not a module.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\kontakt\kontakt-delete-dialog.component.ts 6:31-50
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\kontakt\kontakt-delete-dialog.component.ts(6,32)
      TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/entities/kontakt/kontakt.service.ts' is not a module.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\kontakt\kontakt-delete-dialog.component.ts 7:34-68
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\entities\kontakt\kontakt-delete-dialog.component.ts(7,35)
      TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/shared/model/kontakt.model.ts' is not a module.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\app.component.ts 12:33-66
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\app.component.ts(12,34)
      TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/core/icons/font-awesome-icons.ts' is not a module.
ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\app.component.ts 13:77-94
[tsl] ERROR in C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\app.component.ts(13,78)
      TS2306: File 'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/app.constants.ts' is not a module.

This is not the whole list of weird errors I get because it is quite a long list:)
I tried different workarounds and solutions suggested on internet but nothing worked for me.
Thanks in advance,
Zoran

You have lots of issues but most seems to point to eslint:
Error mentioned in the comments


Ok, here is the one you might be interested to start with: ERROR in ./src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts
(C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\layouts\navbar\navbar.component.ts)
19:4-7 [tsl] ERROR in
C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\layouts\navbar\navbar.component.ts(19,5)
TS2403: Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type.
Variable '_c0' must be of type '() => string[]', but here has type '()
=> { exact: boolean; }'.


This code fixes it has you are go to line19 in navbar.component.ts and find where _c0 is declared or used, add this
let _c0: () => string[] | { exact: boolean; };



Error:  Hmmm, this is the interesting error I just provoked: ERROR src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.component.ts:40:7 - error
TS2322: Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'false'. 40
this.inProduction = profileInfo.inProduction; and it occured when I
reaplaced 'inProduction: boolean = false;' with 'inProduction: false;'
Maybe some of tsconfig.json properties are not correct? inProduction
should be of type boolean automaticly when I say 'inProduction:
false;'?!?!


Explanation:
There should be a clear distinction between literal type values and boolean values when you make a declaration such as inProduction = false it would always be false but when you declare something has below it can be seen/expressed as a flag which can change.
inProduction: boolean = false;
Here is a code to fix it Line 40-> navbar.component.ts:40:7 -
inProduction: boolean = false;


Error: 3

These is also 1 error interesting to start with (there are 16 error
with same message): 'ERROR in
C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\app.component.ts
12:33-66 [tsl] ERROR in
C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects\isb\src\main\webapp\app\app.component.ts(12,34)
TS2306: File
'C:/Users/Zoran/IdeaProjects/isb/src/main/webapp/app/core/icons/font-awesome-icons.ts'
is not a module.'

Possible issues

The issue is the way you are importing it , first go to your tsconfig.json file check the moduleResolution setting in tsconfig.json. If set to node, you must import things as node would.

something like this
NB Buttefly represents the icon you have in that file part.
import { Buttefly } from './core/icons/font-awesome-icons';  

or
import Buttefly from './core/icons/font-awesome-icons'; 


I would check this file in question font-awesome-icons.ts see if it has an export statements in it. For TS to treat a file as a module, it needs to export something (e.g a function, a class etc).

Finally, make ensure the file path in the import statement is relative to app.component.ts


But for we begin debugging as to why you don't get error from ng serve, the simple answer Angular might look for packages globally that is outside your project I would imagine and it then resolves it.
So if you have the latest version(s) of a particular package it will not complain, but with node.js
But for more information about that here is an
old_stack_over_flow_question you can look it up.
Having said that, I would advise try and trace it(errors) systematically, some I have been able to identify some which are.
Error 1. Fix ESLint Plugin Issue: @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin
`npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin --save-dev`

Error 2.
npm install @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin @typescript-eslint/parser eslint --save-dev

Check for compatibility issues with  .eslintrc.json to ensure the configuration is compatible with the installed ESLint version.

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:   [eslint] Failed to load
plugin '@typescript-eslint' declared in '--config': Cannot find module
'@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin'   Require stack:

C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects_placeholder_.js   Referenced from: C:\Users\Zoran\IdeaProjects.eslintrc.json


Error 3. You have a mismatch with angular libraries, which was what Angular found in relation with JIT compilation
Do a ng update
 ng update && npm install -g @angular/cli


core.mjs:3476 JIT compilation failed for injectable class
PlatformNavigation {
static { this.ɵfac = angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0_["ɵɵngDeclareFactory"]({ minVersion: "12.0.0", version: "18.2.1", ngImport:
_angular_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MOD… getCompilerFacade   @   core.mjs:3476

Error 4:
Your typescript version is also not happy..
npm install typescript@latest --save-dev

I would advise you backup your node_modules if you think there are some third party libs that are deprecated and you still use them. Then do a fresh installation.
rm -rf node_modules
npm install

Then run the command you usually run before for example:
npm run start
npm run webpack:dev

Finally do a bit of house-cleaning with all your components imports paths and all.
NOTE:
It is usually better to upgrade one version after another so do 14 to 15, then 16 not 14 to 18 ...
I hope this helps you!

I found the answer on my question!
I was really really stuck with this one and this error was also the root cause for bunch of other very strange errors.
As I already said, I tried different workarounds and solutions suggested on internet but nothing worked for me. Finally I found this one which made most of my errors to disappear and made my day: Angular 14: The injectable 'PlatformLocation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available. I did what was suggested and I changed my webpack.config.mjs as:
    new AngularWebpackPlugin({
        mainPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
        tsConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json'),
        sourceMap: true,
        jitMode: '@angular/compiler' <-- replaced jitMode: false with this}),

And voila, it worked, the magic happened! The most important thing is that error I mentioned at the beginning was finally solved along with other weird errors at the same time! I tried to find explanation in documentation but it is always said that AOT has to be set to false and jitMode set to true and vice versa (depends on what you want). But, I found the explanation at the end. From the documentation provided in answer's link, you will think that jitMode has to be boolean (default is false) which is not the truth, jitMode can have a value '@angular/compiler'!
Explanation:

"How to Enable JIT Compilation:
In your AngularWebpackPlugin configuration, you enable JIT mode by setting jitMode to '@angular/compiler':
JavaScript
new AngularWebpackPlugin({
   mainPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/main/webapp/app/app.main.ts'),
   tsConfigPath: path.resolve(__dirname, '../tsconfig.json'),
   sourceMap: true,
   jitMode: '@angular/compiler'
}),

This configuration tells Angular to use the JIT compiler provided by
the @angular/compiler package.
Purpose of JIT mode (@angular/compiler):
In this context, setting jitMode to @angular/compiler ensures that the Angular compiler is included to compile the templates dynamically at runtime rather than pre-compiling them during the build process."

Notice: Yes, explanation was provided by AI assistant.
Conclusion: The runtime error "The injectable 'PlatformNavigation' needs to be compiled using the JIT compiler, but '@angular/compiler' is not available." was the root cause for all other weird errors I was getting.
For everyone who are facing the similar type of error, try this solution first before you waste your time trying some workarounds or whatever (as I did)!
I also forgot to mention that in my angular.json, AOT flags are set to true which means that it will use JIT compiler only when it is needed in a runtime and the rest of the code will be compiled using AOT mode.
And at the end I would like to add just few advices from my experience while migrating from node 14 to node 18.

ng-jhipster package is very old and there are no updates for it yet. Because of that, you will have to find replacements for some things. For example, if you are using translations (i18n) then you have to know that jhiTranslate doesn't work anymore in node 18 in your templates. There will be no errors during compilation but there will be no translations too. You will have to use translation pipes and/or [translate] from @ngx-translate/core package instead. In app.module.ts:

...
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { TranslateModule, TranslateLoader } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TranslateHttpLoader } from '@ngx-translate/http-loader';
...
function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient):TranslateHttpLoader {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, '../i18n/', '.json');
}
...
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    TranslateModule.forRoot({
      loader: {
        provide: TranslateLoader,
        useFactory: HttpLoaderFactory,
        deps: [HttpClient]
      },
    }),
...the rest of your import
  ],
...the rest of your app.module.ts

I am using translation pipes e.g.
{{ 'isbApp.company.home.title' | translate }}

where isbApp.company.home.title is path to translation in your JSON translation file in 'i18n' folder.
So, replace all your jhiTranslate in HTML templates with [translate] or translate pipes.
You can also try to use translate.directive.ts which is a wrapper for 'ngx-translate/core' so you should be able to keep your HTML template as it is without replacing jhiTranslate attributes:
//translate.directive.ts
import { inject, Input, Directive, ElementRef, OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { translationNotFoundMessage } from '../../config/translation.config';

/**
 * A wrapper directive on top of the translate pipe as the inbuilt translate directive from ngx-translate is too verbose and buggy
 */
@Directive({
  selector: '[jhiTranslate]',
})
export class TranslateDirective implements OnChanges, OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() jhiTranslate!: string;
  @Input() translateValues?: { [key: string]: unknown };

  private readonly directiveDestroyed = new Subject();

  private el = inject(ElementRef);
  private translateService = inject(TranslateService);

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.translateService.onLangChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.directiveDestroyed)).subscribe(() => {
      this.getTranslation();
    });
    this.translateService.onTranslationChange.pipe(takeUntil(this.directiveDestroyed)).subscribe(() => {
      this.getTranslation();
    });
  }

  ngOnChanges(): void {
    this.getTranslation();
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.directiveDestroyed.next(null);
    this.directiveDestroyed.complete();
  }

  private getTranslation(): void {
    this.translateService
      .get(this.jhiTranslate, this.translateValues)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.directiveDestroyed))
      .subscribe({
        next: value => {
          this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = value;
        },
        error: () => `${translationNotFoundMessage}[${this.jhiTranslate}]`,
      });
  }
}

Notice: I never used it so I am not sure if it works.

Also, tslint is obsolete. You'll have to use eslint instead which means changes in your webpack rules and plugins. Similar thing is for typescript and javascript webpack rules. For ts you should use something like:

    module: {
        rules: [
           {
                test: /\.(ts)$/,
                use: ['ts-loader', 'angular2-template-loader'],
                exclude: /node_modules/,
           },

and for js you should use babel:
           {
              test: /\.m?js$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                  plugins: [linkerPlugin],
                  compact: false,
                  cacheDirectory: true,                },
              },
           },


For scss maybe you will have to use 'to-string-loader' and 'style-loader' for different scss files. Something like:

            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: { implementation: sass }
                }],
                exclude: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/
            },
            {
                test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
                use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', {
                    loader: 'sass-loader',
                    options: { implementation: sass }
                }]
            },


Pay attention on JIT and AOT because it can be very tricky so look at my explanation I gave here.
Probably you will have to add some new packages in package.json but it will complain about missing packages so you should solve it easily. Also, you will probably have to change your tsconfig.json but just follow the error messages and you should be fine. Same thing is with typescipt components and HTML templates. Probably you'll get some error messages but just follow them and again, you should be fine.
Be careful about circular dependencies. If you get error like 'Out of memory' or some similar error while building the solution, you should suspect that there is a circular dependency. I use 'madge' so in my project root directory I execute 'madge --circular .' and it happened to me that I had circular dependencies discovered by 'madge'. Unfortunately 'madge' is not a magic wand so sometimes it can't see the circular dependency if it's deep and complex e.g. interceptors.
In your webpack.config.js/mjs you can also add (as I did) :

    new CircularDependencyPlugin({
        exclude: /node_modules|test|target/,
        include: /src/,
        failOnError: true,
        allowAsyncCycles: false,
        cwd: process.cwd(),
        onStart({ compilation }) {
          console.log('Start detecting webpack modules cycles');
        },
        onDetected({ module: webpackModuleRecord, paths, compilation }) {
          const dependencyPaths = paths.join(' -> ');
          console.error(`Circular dependency detected: ${dependencyPaths}`);
          compilation.errors.push(new Error(dependencyPaths));
        },
        onEnd({ compilation }) {
          console.log('End detecting webpack modules cycles');
        },
    }),

so it will look for circular dependencies each time you build your solution.
Never do this in your module (if you don't use standalone components):
//Module1
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Component1,
...
,
  ],
  imports: [
    Component1,
...
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class Module1 {}

You will get 'Out of memory' error or some similar error during the build because of circular dependency. I think that same thing will happen if you have something like:
//Module1
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Component1,
...
,
  ],
  imports: [
...
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class Module1 {}

//Module2
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
...
,
  ],
  imports: [
    Component1,
...
  ],
  exports: [],
})
export class Module2 {}


Few more advices: always compile your code with 'ng build' and with 'npm run start'. For some errors npm will not complain but 'ng build' will. Also, use 'npm install --legacy-peer-deps' or 'yarn install'. It will complain if there are some dependency issues and it will report them but it will not stop the installation of 'node_modules'.
I hope this will help someone.
